# Core Data and unix timestamp date

Tags: ios, date, core-data, nspredicate

I have Core Data with User Locations: longitude,latitude etc.

And i try get list of available days:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Locations" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"device_id == %@", deviceID];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;

[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"created_at"]];

[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];


NSMutableArray *dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSDateFormatter *formatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary* obj in results ) {


    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[obj valueForKey:@"created_at"] integerValue]];

    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    if (dateArray.count == 0) {
        [dateArray addObject:dateString];
    }
    else{
        if (![dateArray containsObject:dateString]) {
            [dateArray addObject:dateString];
        }
    }


}
NSLog(@"Object: %@", dateArray);
```

everything works fine but when i have many position in Core Data this take a while... any ideas how i can modified CoreData Request to make this faster ?

Comment: Hey, do you really need all dates from the database? If  not you should use a more specific predicate like `created_at > x days ago`. Some other improvments : Your  condition `(dateArray.count == 0)` is not necessary and you should only create the NSDateFormatter once before you loop through your array

Comment: I have date in unix timestemp (like "1427896596") and need get list of day (like 12-03-2015,13-03-2015 etc)

Comment: "SELECT  DISTINCT date(time, 'unixepoch') as days FROM children_position WHERE child_id=2" maybe this sql query its good but i dont know how convert this to CoreData execution :)